# Solving a system of equation with complex number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^2-3y^2=6$
$xy=3$

I got the $x$'s for it already: $x = \pm i\sqrt3$, and $x = \pm3$

For the complex number that contains the $i$, I would just plug it into $y$ for one of the equations right? I do that, but I get $y = \pm i\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plugging $$y=\frac{3}{x}$$ in your first equation we get
$$x^2-\frac{27}{x^2}=6$$ multiplying by $x^2$ we get
$$x^4-6x^2-27=0$$ can you solve this equation?

Comment: (x^2-9)(x^2+3) Then I get x = +-3 and x=+- isqrt(3)

Comment: ok, and then you must compute $y$

Comment: y = +-1 and y = ±isqrt(3)?

Comment: $x=-3,y=-1$ or $x=3,y=1$

Comment: $x=-i\sqrt{3},y=i\sqrt{3}$ or $x=i\sqrt{3},y=-i\sqrt{3}$